# Trying to create a dice game in R but function not running

Tags: r

I have a code to make a game where a person rolls the die 4 times and if a roll lands on 6, they win. However, I'm running the code but it doesn't produce an output.

```
game<-function (n=4){
  count=0
  ceiling(6*runif(1))
  for(i in 1:n){
    if(ceiling(6*runif(1))==6){
      count=1
    }
    else(
      count=0
    )
 if(count=1){
   print("Win")}
  else{
    print("Lose")
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're missing the == in the if(count==1)

Comment: Also note the way this currently works, you'll only return `Win` if the last roll == 6 when you probably want them to have four changes to win.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using `any` to see if any roll equals to `6`, then use `return` to report the value.

```
game <- function(n = 4){
  if (any(ceiling(6 * runif(n)) == 6L)){
    return("Win")
  } else {
    return("Lose")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can in fact do it much simpler using `ifelse` to vectorise the `if` statement. Also, you can avoid intermediate variables (e.g. `count`):

```
game<-function (n=4){
  ifelse(6 %in% sample(6, n, replace = TRUE), "Win", "Lose")
}
```